# Call an async function and don't wait for its result

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous

I have 2 functions: fA and fB.

```
fun fA() {
    (calculations -> rA)
    fB(rA)
    return rA
}

fun fB(r: String) {
    (more calculations -> rB)
    return rB
}
```

At the end of fA, I want to call fB and then right away return rA, without the need of waiting for the calculation, the result, the possible errors, or anything of fB. How can I do that?

I was reading https://kotlinlang.org/docs/async-programming.html but maybe I missed it.

Comment: Why would you return a value that you need a calculation on before the calculation happens. Your return from fB() would be DOA. And if you scroll down to Coroutines, it tells you how to do asynch the Kotlin way.

Comment: What is the point of calculating `rB` if you don't use it anywhere? Does `fB()` has side-effects? Generally, you need to decide on which concurrency framework do you want to use. In Kotlin we are encouraged to use coroutines, but they have their own learning curve. It also depends if you want to create a good and reliable code which behaves correctly in the case of failures, cancellations, etc. or it just throws asynchronous tasks into the black hole and doesn't care about them.

Comment: If you use Kotlin on the JVM, you can call `CompletableFuture.runAsync { fB(rA) }`. It will effectively submit the task on one of JVM common fork-join pool asynchronously. Without more code, result/errors will be lost.

Comment: @broot Yes, fB() has side effects, there is a reason to call and run it.

Comment: @amanin Thanks, I think this is what I need. Is "CompletableFuture.runAsync { fB(rA) }" the Java way or the Kotlin way?

Comment: Presumably you'll eventually want to access these ‘side effects’ from other thread(s)? If so, you'll need to take care to do so in a thread-safe way, to avoid the risk of accessing part-completed — or, worse, completed but part-published — results.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.runAsync {}` is a purely Java solution. Kotlin equivalent would be: `GlobalScope.launch {}`. But it doesn't really matter, they both do a pretty similar thing. Please be aware in both cases you should avoid blocking the thread in `fB()`. You can also start a new thread easily by: `thread { ... }`.

Comment: I mean, neither of those are good ideas, for reasons discussed in the GlobalScope documentation.  You should generally be creating and managing scopes.

Comment: @everyone After some trial and error, this is what worked for me:
```
fun fA() {
    (calculations -> rA)
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        fB(rA)
    }
    return rA
}
```
Which is what I needed: fA triggers fB and then keeps running, without waiting for fB to finish.
Is this correct?